# Jquery Active page link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Need some help with this code I got off the net

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".linkbar li").each(function(){
var href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
if (href === window.location.pathname) {
$(this).addClass('current');
}
});
});
```

if I do 
document.write(href);

I get "undefined"

If I place var `href = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');` before `.each()` function it changes all my links to the current class

below is my HTML and CSS
I need to change the css link for the current page, I'm not too good with Jquery/JS. Please explain to me what the problem is and how to solve it.

```
<div class ="linkbar">

<a href = "/HTS/about-us.php"><li> ABOUT US </li> </a>
<a href = "service.php"><li> SERVICES </li> </a>
<a href = "download.php"><li> DOWNLOAD </li> </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.linkbar li{
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
list-style-type: none;
font-size:11px;
width:auto;
padding:9px 18px 9px 18px;
}

.current{
background-color:#fecd0f;
vertical-align:center;
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `document.write()`, it uses `document.open()` which wipes out all the previous code. Use `alert()` or `console.log()` instead. Secondly, comparing `location.pathname` to value in `href` attribute fails in many browsers, due to some browsers automatically complete the `href` to be a full address with protocol-part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, buddy you have .find() which finds inside the element and you anchor tag as parent of li tag so instead of that use this:

```
var href = $(this).parent('a').attr('href');
```

if it was this you have this:

```
<li><a href = "/HTS/about-us.php"> ABOUT US  </a></li>
<li><a href = "service.php"> SERVICES </a></li>
<li><a href = "download.php"> DOWNLOAD  </a></li>
```

still never use `find()` but use this :

```
var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. `<li>` tags must be inside `<ul>` tag. Put `<a>` tags into `<li>` tags to make `find("a")` work:

```
<ul class ="linkbar">
  <li><a href = "/HTS/about-us.php">ABOUT US </a></li> 
  <li><a href = "service.php">SERVICES </a></li> 
  <li><a href = "download.php">DOWNLOAD </a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should remove the class and then add the class you can refer to Jquery document for more information :
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
$(this).removeClass(".linkbar li").addClass('current');
```

and you should absolutely put li tags inside ul